# Searching via Category DropDownList ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am looking for some help with searching for `Stockitems` in my application.  Within the home view there is a drop down list of Categories (Boots, socks etc..) next to this is a Search box that I would like to use to search for all items within the selected category.

The database table relationship is as follows:

`- Category > SubCategory > StockItems`

The `DDL` is a `HTML.DropDownList` that passes back the selected category and is picked up by the `Controller` using `Request["DDLName"]`. Would it then be possible to return `stockitem`s that are a part of the selected category to the view using `LINQ`?

With the following attempt, I currently get:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Classes are as follows -

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SubCategory> SubCategory { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual List<StockItem> Items { get; set; }
}


public class StockItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public long Barcode { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public int StockItemID { get; set; }
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }
}
```

Controller currently has the following for index -

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString) 

ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(_categoryRepo.getCategories(), "Name", "Name"); 
var strDDLValue = Request["CategoryID"]; 

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strDDLValue)) items = items.Where(r => r.SubCategory.Category.Name.Equals(strDDLValue) && r.Title.Contains(searchString))

return View(item);
```

Comment: What are you already doing in your controller? Why is it failing? In general, yes, you can do what you're saying, but it's hard to provide helpful response without a clear question to answer. High level: pass through an id from your dropdown to your controller. Don't read from Request[""], but rather pass in a structured viewmodel with the value.

Comment: first with name get CategortId and then use GetAllSubCategry().Where(a=> a.CategoryID == selectedCategoryId).SelectMany(a=> a.Items);

Comment: @cyhyraeth please edit your question to include this information in a formatted code block instead of having it in a plaintext comment.  Also, if you could say what you've tried, and how it's failed, in your actual question, that would help.  Thanks!

Comment: Added some more detail to my question - thanks for the help so far guys. Jonathan can you clarify passing through a VM from the view to the controller? Please let me know if you need any other details

Comment: Thanks @Max von Hippel have added some more information...

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out in the end...final controller class as follows -

```
  public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(_categoryRepo.getCategories(), "ID", "Name");

        // ViewModel

        var items = _stockRepo.getStock().Select(r => r.toStockVM());

        // Search

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            searchString = searchString.ToUpper();
            items = items.Where(r => 
                      r.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["CategoryID"]))
        {
            var strDDLValue = Convert.ToInt32(Request["CategoryID"]);

            if (strDDLValue >= 1)
            {
                searchString = searchString.ToUpper();
                items = items.Where(r => r.SubCateogory.CategoryID == strDDLValue && r.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchString));
            }
        }

        return View(items);
    }
```

Cheers for your comments. Happy to elaborate on anything if anyone else encounters the same issues.